# ipython3 shell freezes on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, ubuntu-18.04

After some time my python code that I run in ipython shell freezes. I have found entries in the syslog file. I will need to investigate that.

By freezing I mean:

1. the process in the shell stops
2. the shell is not responding to keystrokes

Does anyone have any advice/suggestions about what might be going on and where should I look? I understand it is a vague question but maybe we can all get to the bottom of the problem. Thank you!

**Configuration of my system.**

```
$ ipython3 --version
7.14.0
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
$ ipython3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jul 17 2020, 12:50:27) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.14.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: exit                                                                                                                                                  
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

I have looked at syslog and found this.

```
    Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066680] python3: page allocation failure: order:4, mode:0x14040c0(GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_COMP), nodemask=(null)
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066681] python3 cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066684] CPU: 11 PID: 1241 Comm: python3 Not tainted 4.15.0-109-generic #110-Ubuntu
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066685] Hardware name: LENOVO 30C50045US/3138, BIOS M1VKT1BA 08/17/2018
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066686] Call Trace:
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066690]  dump_stack+0x6d/0x8e
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066693]  warn_alloc+0xff/0x1a0
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066694]  ? __alloc_pages_direct_compact+0x51/0x100
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066695]  __alloc_pages_slowpath+0xdc5/0xe00
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066697]  __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x29a/0x2c0
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066699]  alloc_pages_current+0x6a/0xe0
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066701]  kmalloc_order+0x18/0x40
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066702]  kmalloc_order_trace+0x24/0xb0
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066703]  __kmalloc+0x1fe/0x210
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066706]  proc_do_submiturb+0x4a3/0xd90
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066707]  usbdev_do_ioctl+0xa38/0x1170
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066709]  usbdev_ioctl+0xe/0x20
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066711]  do_vfs_ioctl+0xa8/0x630
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066712]  ? SyS_futex+0x13b/0x180
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066713]  SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066714]  do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066716]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x41/0xa6
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066717] RIP: 0033:0x7f8abc0b56d7
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066718] RSP: 002b:00007f89ca386a98 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066719] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000002057f90 RCX: 00007f8abc0b56d7
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066719] RDX: 00007f8a2c0077c0 RSI: 000000008038550a RDI: 0000000000000022
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066720] RBP: 00007f8a2c006e40 R08: 00007f8a2c0077c0 R09: 00007f8a2c008430
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066720] R10: 00000000ffffff00 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066721] R13: 00007f8a2c0077c0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066722] warn_alloc_show_mem: 1 callbacks suppressed
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066722] Mem-Info:
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066724] active_anon:7072912 inactive_anon:510142 isolated_anon:0
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066724]  active_file:7178154 inactive_file:1236198 isolated_file:0
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066724]  unevictable:12 dirty:582646 writeback:328149 unstable:6144
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066724]  slab_reclaimable:204738 slab_unreclaimable:31575
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066724]  mapped:16191 shmem:10145 pagetables:27672 bounce:0
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066724]  free:84911 free_pcp:15 free_cma:0
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066726] Node 0 active_anon:28291648kB inactive_anon:2040568kB active_file:28712940kB inactive_file:4944792kB u$
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066726] Node 0 DMA free:15888kB min:16kB low:28kB high:40kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB $
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066728] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2326 64192 64192 64192
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066729] Node 0 DMA32 free:249952kB min:2448kB low:4828kB high:7208kB active_anon:1548208kB inactive_anon:52kB $
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066731] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 61865 61865 61865
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066732] Node 0 Normal free:73804kB min:65116kB low:128464kB high:191812kB active_anon:26743080kB inactive_anon$
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066733] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066734] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB (U) 0*32kB 2*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*20$
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066737] Node 0 DMA32: 54*4kB (UME) 74*8kB (UME) 280*16kB (UME) 225*32kB (UME) 319*64kB (UME) 276*128kB (UME) 2$
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066740] Node 0 Normal: 6*4kB (UH) 233*8kB (UMH) 2952*16kB (UMEH) 723*32kB (UEH) 1*64kB (H) 3*128kB (H) 3*256kB$
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066744] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066744] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066744] 8446758 total pagecache pages
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066753] 21866 pages in swap cache
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066754] Swap cache stats: add 268953271, delete 268898216, find 41931219/53685984
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066754] Free swap  = 65004764kB
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066754] Total swap = 67108860kB
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066755] 16733480 pages RAM
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066755] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066755] 284837 pages reserved
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066755] 0 pages cma reserved
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066706]  proc_do_submiturb+0x4a3/0xd90
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066707]  usbdev_do_ioctl+0xa38/0x1170
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066709]  usbdev_ioctl+0xe/0x20
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066711]  do_vfs_ioctl+0xa8/0x630
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066712]  ? SyS_futex+0x13b/0x180
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066713]  SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066714]  do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066716]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x41/0xa6
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066717] RIP: 0033:0x7f8abc0b56d7
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066718] RSP: 002b:00007f89ca386a98 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066719] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000002057f90 RCX: 00007f8abc0b56d7
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066719] RDX: 00007f8a2c0077c0 RSI: 000000008038550a RDI: 0000000000000022
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066720] RBP: 00007f8a2c006e40 R08: 00007f8a2c0077c0 R09: 00007f8a2c008430
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066720] R10: 00000000ffffff00 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066721] R13: 00007f8a2c0077c0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066722] warn_alloc_show_mem: 1 callbacks suppressed
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066722] Mem-Info:
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066724] active_anon:7072912 inactive_anon:510142 isolated_anon:0
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066724]  active_file:7178154 inactive_file:1236198 isolated_file:0
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066724]  unevictable:12 dirty:582646 writeback:328149 unstable:6144
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066724]  slab_reclaimable:204738 slab_unreclaimable:31575
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066724]  mapped:16191 shmem:10145 pagetables:27672 bounce:0
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066724]  free:84911 free_pcp:15 free_cma:0
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066726] Node 0 active_anon:28291648kB inactive_anon:2040568kB active_file:28712940kB inactive_file:4944792kB u$
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066726] Node 0 DMA free:15888kB min:16kB low:28kB high:40kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB $
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066728] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2326 64192 64192 64192
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066729] Node 0 DMA32 free:249952kB min:2448kB low:4828kB high:7208kB active_anon:1548208kB inactive_anon:52kB $
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066731] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 61865 61865 61865
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066732] Node 0 Normal free:73804kB min:65116kB low:128464kB high:191812kB active_anon:26743080kB inactive_anon$
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066733] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066734] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB (U) 0*32kB 2*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*20$
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066737] Node 0 DMA32: 54*4kB (UME) 74*8kB (UME) 280*16kB (UME) 225*32kB (UME) 319*64kB (UME) 276*128kB (UME) 2$
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066740] Node 0 Normal: 6*4kB (UH) 233*8kB (UMH) 2952*16kB (UMEH) 723*32kB (UEH) 1*64kB (H) 3*128kB (H) 3*256kB$
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066744] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066744] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066744] 8446758 total pagecache pages
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066753] 21866 pages in swap cache
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066754] Swap cache stats: add 268953271, delete 268898216, find 41931219/53685984
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066754] Free swap  = 65004764kB
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066754] Total swap = 67108860kB
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066755] 16733480 pages RAM
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066755] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066755] 284837 pages reserved
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066755] 0 pages cma reserved
Aug 12 20:52:57 linux-box kernel: [3135203.066756] 0 pages hwpoisoned
```

**Few words about what I do. might be useful, might be not.**

I have a code that communicates with a camera, reads images and saves them. I have two threads per python process. One for reading images from the camera and one for saving them into a file.